# The difference between $F(a)$, $F[a]$, $F_q$, and $F_{q^m}$ in ring theory and coding theory

Tags: ring-theory, notation, coding-theory

I'm a little confused by some notation in ring theory and coding theory. 
Assume $F$ is a field.
What does the following notation mean 
(with some examples to understand better)?

- $F(a)$ -- I think this is the smallest field containing $F$ and the root $a$. Is my definition correct??
- $F[a]$?
- $F_q$? (in coding theory)
- $F_{q^m}$

(I know that $F[x]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients in $F$.)

Comment: Yes $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$. And $F[a]$ is the smallest ring containing $F$ and $a$. This element $a$ can be : algebraic over $F$ ($a = \sqrt{2}$, the root of a polynomial $P \in F[X]$) or transcendental over $F$ ($a = \pi$ or $a =X$)

Comment: Now $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the finite field (if it exists it is unique) with $q$ elements, and $\mathbb{F}_{q^m} = \mathbb{F}_q(\alpha)  \simeq \mathbb{F}_{q}[X]/(P)$ is a finite (algebraic) extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$  of degree $[\mathbb{F}_{q^m}:\mathbb{F}_q] = m$,  with $P\in\mathbb{F}_q[X]$ irreducible of degree $m$ and $P(\alpha)=0$

Comment: You seem to be asking several different questions here, which you don't get to until halfway through your post. In the future, try to make your question and title direct, clear, and to the point.

Comment: @6005 I don't agree. This is hard to follow, and the question is good.

Comment: @user1952009 If you can restate it to be a good, clear quesiton, why don't you? Editing questions is not done often enough. I do agree now that I see what the OP is saying there is a good question hiding here.

Comment: @user1952009, and Andrew New: I have edited the question to clean it up, and upvoted it! :) Much better.

Comment: Basically you want to focus on getting to your question as fast as possible, don't talk about how you are confused or why you are posting your question. Just state directly what you want to know, both in the title and in the body, and if you want you can add some context after you state the question.